# Generate resource usage report

Tags: resources

I'm looking for load/usage data for a server in terms of CPU/RAM/network/Disk from OS perspective.  The OS is RHEL5.  I know sar is able to report system activity info, but the only commands I know are "sar -r -f sa10" and "sar -q -f sa10", and it's in hourly format.

I would like to generate resource (CPU/RAM/network/Disk) usage report over the past month.  Is sar able to do this?  If yes, how?  If no, what tool I can use to generate this quickly.

Example:

```
11/01/11      runq-sz  plist-sz   ldavg-1   ldavg-5  ldavg-15
11/01/11            0       137      0.00      0.00      0.00
11/02/11            3       139      0.00      0.00      0.00
11/03/11            5       139      0.03      0.01      0.00
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know `sar` ([Is this it?](http://www.softpanorama.org/Admin/Monitoring/sar.shtml)), from what you're describing, it might be advisable to have a look at the whole [`RRDtool` complex](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/rrdworld/index.en.html).  You could for example use [`collectd`](http://collectd.org) to collect the data in [`rrd` ("Round-Robin Database") files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-Robin_Database); where data means whatever you want to know the usage of.  There're [lots of plugins](http://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Category%3aPlugins) already, also for CPU, memory, disk and network utilization.  Once you collected the data, you can use some report tool to generate a report, I haven't used any, but [the link from above](http://www.softpanorama.org/Admin/Monitoring/sar.shtml) mentions a few, googling yields for example [`rrd-report`](http://remstats.sourceforge.net/release/rrd-report.html) which could be useful, too.

Another way would be skipping the RRD part (and its advantages) and using `collectd`'s [CSV plugin](http://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin%3aCSV).

**Edit** There're [lots of monitoring/measuring solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collectd#See_also), I just picked `collectd` because it supposedly is light on resources.

**Caveat:** For loooong-time statistics, RRD might not be the best choice as it covers a *constant time span* sliding window -- [see this for an introduction to this database format](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/tut/rrd-beginners.en.html).